# Clojure Vector of maps

Tags: clojure, clojure-repl

I am new to clojure programming and need a little help.
Say I have a vector of maps as shown.

```
(def testVMap 
  [ {:name "AAA" :rate 100 } 
    {:name "GEICO" :rate 120 }
    {:name "PROGRESSIVE" :rate 118} ] )
```

How do I do some operations like finding the rate of AAA or to see if I have the rates for, say ALLSTAR, if rates are not present I would want to able to add it, I know I can add that using into or conj.
But my main concern is finding my map has a particluar name and if name is present I need to update the rate to a new value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one method:

```
(some #(if (= "GEICO" (:name %)) %) testVMap)
```

That says: Return the first thing in `testVMap` whose `:name` is equal to `"GEICO"`.  `#(... % ...)` defines a function, with `%` as its function parameter.  This part `(:name %)` returns the value of the `:name` value for each map.

If there might be multiple "GEICO" maps, and you want them all, use `filter` instead of `some`.

Here's another version:

```
 (some #(and (= "GEICO" (:name %)) %) testVMap)
```

You may want to use `update` as well.

EDIT:
e.g.:

```
(map #(if (= "GEICO" (:name %))
          (update % :rate inc)
          %)
testVMap)
```

Here `inc` is the function that adds 1 to a number.  You should replace that with a function that performs the transformation that you want, such as `#(+ 10 %)`, or `(partial + 10)`, which is the same thing.

The function defined by `#(...)` checks whether the value of `:name` is "GEICO", and then if so, updates the rate with the function that you provide (`inc` in this case); otherwise, `#(...)` returns the map unchanged.

I'll leave it to you to look up the documentation of `update`, if it's not self-explanatory from the context.

You could also use `mapv` instead of `map`.

You'll no doubt want to build all of this into one or more functions.  Remember that functions are things in Clojure--they're "data", first class objects, etc.  So where I used `inc`, you can have a function parameter, and the function you define can accept another function as its argument, which the first function will then use in the `update` part of the code (instead of `inc`).

About adding a map if the one you want doesn't exist: If you're not dealing with a long sequence of maps, I'd consider doing this in a different step.  See Andre's answer for names of functions that are useful for testing whether a collection contains an element.

However, note that testing whether a vector contains something that's not there requires Clojure to look through the entire vector.  It might be better to use a Clojure set rather than a vector, or consider using an outer map with (for example) `:aaa`, `:geico`, etc. as keys.  In that case, take a look at the function `update-in`.

Comment: This says nothing about how to actually *update* an item in the list. Just how to find an item.

Comment: Yes.  That was the basic question--how to find it.  I added a tip about `update` now, but that's extra.

Comment: Thank you.
But I also want to update, say if "GEICO" was found I want to increment rate by 10

Comment: @Mars, `(some #(and (= "GEICO" (:name %))) testVMap)` will return true and not the element. The `and` will get evaluated as `(and true)` or `(and false)`. Your original `if` is correct. If anything, you could replace the `if` with a `when` to denote there is only one branch. An `if` raises the expectation of an `else`.

Comment: @Mars, ah, you must have meant `#(and (= "GEICO" (:name %)) %)`. Yeah, that ought to work.

Comment: @AmithGeorge you're right.  Thanks.  I've fixed it now with your correction.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of telling you straight away how to do this, let me show you how you'd find this kind of function.

These two website structure the functions pretty well:

- https://clojuredocs.org/quickref
- http://conj.io/

Now what you're dealing with is in general a **collection** and if that doesn't do what you want you can look for specific **vector** operations. But the first should be **collection**. You'll then see **Content Tests** section in both sites.

Now you have the following candidates:

```
distinct? empty? every? not-every? some not-any?
```

The right candidate here is `some`:

```
(some (comp (partial = "AAA") :name) testVMap)
;; => true
```

Comment: This says nothing about how to actually *update* an item in the list. Just how to find an item. Also, `some` here doesn't return the item. It returns true/false base on whether the item exists at all.

Comment: Don't forget my favorite, the Clojure Cheatsheet:  http://jafingerhut.github.io/cheatsheet/clojuredocs/cheatsheet-tiptip-cdocs-summary.html

Answer (score 1):

#### Seeing if an item exists

```
(first
  (filter
    (comp #{"AAA"} :name)
    [{:name "AAA" :rate 100}
     {:name "GEICO" :rate 120}
     {:name "PROGRESSIVE" :rate 118}]))
```

#### Updating your structure

If order isn't important, you can reorganize the structure into a map of name->rate. For example:

```
{"AAA" 100 "GEICO" 120}
```

Then you can use `update-in` or `assoc` to update the rate.

If order *is* important, you can do something like this:

```
(mapv
  (fn [{:keys [name] :as v}]
    (if (= name "AAA")
      (assoc v :rate 500)
      v))
  [{:name "AAA" :rate 100}
   {:name "GEICO" :rate 120}
   {:name "PROGRESSIVE" :rate 118}])
```

#### Adding to your structure

You can add to it with a simple `conj`. So you do something like

```
(if (has-item? struct) ;; has-item would be defined using the first section of this answer
  (update-item struct ...) ;; update-item using the second section of this answer
  (conj struct {:name "AAA" :rate 100}))
```

There are other options of course, but these would be the first that I would go to.

Comment: Thanks I can update the rate if AAA is found but how do I add a new map to the vector if AAA is not found?